# Java regex string output not as expected

Tags: java, regex, validation, email

I'm trying to write some code to validate email addresses based on specific guidelines given to me, and one of the guidelines is that an address such as cath@[10.1.1] should be valid. I've gotten stuck and can't figure out what's wrong with my regex string:

```
 "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+[@|_at_]+[\\[|[A-Za-z0-9-]]+[0-9\\.|_dot_]+[\\]|com|com.au|co.ca|co.nz|co.us|co.uk]{2,4}"
```

this is some example output:

```
Enter an email address
cath@[10.1.1]
cath@[10.1.1] is not a valid email address
cath@[10.1.1.a]
cath@[10.1.1.a] is a valid email address
cath@[10.1.1.]
cath@[10.1.1.] is a valid email address
```

The last two input/outputs should be invalid, whilst the first should be valid. Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction? Thanks

EDIT - here is my code if it helps anyone

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailAddresses {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line;        
    System.out.println("Enter an email address");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

      line = scan.nextLine();
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+(?:@|_at_)(?:\\[|[A-Za-z0-9-])(?:0-9\\.|_dot_)(?:\\]|com|com\\.au|co\\.ca|co\\.nz|co\\.us|co\\.uk){2,4}");
      Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(line);

      if(mat.matches()){
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(line + " is a valid email address");
      }else{
        System.out.println(line + " is not a valid email address");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use _one_ regex for that? It'd be easier to separate the job

Comment: No I don't have to, I just didn't know I could separate it?

Comment: Well, for instance, start to try and find the separator (either `@` or `_at_`), split against it, validate the two parts separately etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the regex flavor understands with the initial regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

I think there is a misconcepttion. Brackets `[]` create a character class: a sequence of **characters** alternatives.

Here brackets are used to declare a sequence of words alternatives, that's not the intented behavior. For declaring sequence of words alternatives, use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and inside this group , use the logical operator `|`.

For example:

`"[\\[|[A-Za-z0-9-]]+"` becomes `"(?:\\[|[A-Za-z0-9-])+"`

Try this regex instead:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+(?:@|_at_)(?:\[(?:\d|\.|_dot_)+(?<!\.)\]|[A-Za-z\d._-]+\.(?:com|com\.au|co\.ca|co\.nz|co\.us|co\.uk))$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/dS8qF4

Comment: The dots in the last group should also be escaped

Comment: @fge Thanks to your remark, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Alex, where to generate such diagrams ?

Comment: Hi, thanks. What do the question marks do? - nevermind you have updated your answer. I tried this regex string and none of the above example inputs are valid

Comment: thanks for the diagrams and explanation, cleared lots of the confusion. will give it another go in the morning

Comment: @Luke I have reworked the regex based on my understandings. I have removed `{2,4}` quantifier because I didn't understand the reason of its presence. Anyway, I hope the new regex and its demo will lead you to the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, accepted your answer as it was very helpful. The only thing I had to change was the escape characters, java requires double backslash

Comment: also had to add in another non capturing group for the `_dot_` being used in an email such as `gerry_at_research.techies_dot_co.uk`. All working thanks!

Comment: @Alex, I don't understand why when I type an email like `bob@bob@gmail@gmail.com` it allows this to be valid?

Comment: @Luke There was a little mistake. I introduced a range in the character class `.-_` thus allowing `@` as a valid character. I removed this range and changed it with `._-`. I have provided a new demo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not restricted to using a single regex, I suggest you split the check.

For instance, here is a method which will try and find the separator in your input:

```
private static int trySeparator(final String input, final String separator)
{
    int ret = input.indexOf(separator);
    if (ret == -1)
        return ret;
    return ret == input.lastIndexOf(separator) ? ret : -1;
}
```

Use that within your main validation method for `@` and `_at_`, then separate the first and second parts and check them separately. Much easier than a single regex, more testable ;)

Comment: how would I distinguish between an `_at_` in the mailbox name and the `at` which separates the mailbox name and domain name? i.e. `bob_at_home_at_gmail.com`

Comment: I suggest to use `_at_`, not `at`. Also note that the above method returns -1 if the separator is found more than once.

Comment: thanks for your help, will implement in the morning when i'm less tired :)